# How to rename the files in the path with the new names from the .txt file in batch?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I have two .txt files. The first one contains the list of pathes to the CD-Images:

```
C:\Users\N\Desktop\LOG_Dateien_CD_Imaging\BFU_KONGRESS_9.ISO   
C:\Users\N\Desktop\LOG_Dateien_CD_Imaging\NDC2005.ISO
```

The second one contains the new names for this files

```
490628001
684654326
```

So the file `BFU_KONGRESS_9.ISO` in the directory (not in the .txt file!) should be renamed to `490628001.ISO`
and `NDC2005.ISO` to `684654326.ISO`. The renaming should go line per line

Answer (score 3):

you need a way to read two files in parallel:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

<out.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (in.txt) do (
    set /p out=
    echo rename "%%~a" "!out!"
  )
)
```

Another way: read both files (one after the other) into two arrays and then work with the array variables, but it's more code and might have issues with very large files.