# Batch comparing 2 differents csv files

Tags: csv, batch-file

I havent find anything on internet so i need your help.

I have 2 CSV Files that i would like to compare:

**the first one is like :**

*"Name","PrimarySmtpAddress","EmailAddresses"*

**the second one is like :**

*"Name","$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()"*

the output file must show which name is both in first and second files

And i want to have, as output, a file with all the data in the first files but with the *"$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()"* added a the end of each lines.

**for exemple it would do something like** :

*"Name","PrimarySmtpAddress","EmailAddresses","$_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()",*

I must be not very clear because me english is not perfect.
Can you guys please help me ? im not very good at scripting.
thank you very much.

edit :

```
REM @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set var1
set var2

for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%A in (file2.txt) do (
   set var1=%%A
   echo %var1%

   for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%B in (file1.txt) do (
      set var2=%%B
      echo %var2%
      if ("%var1%"=="%var2%")
      (
         echo equal var
      )
      else
      (
         echo not equal var
      )
   pause
   )
)
pause
```

It looks like the IF is not working

Comment: Not being good at scripting does not exempt you from doing some research and showing some efforts! Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: i didnt ask someone to do it for me, sorry if its look like i did.
i have find multiple topic where people only wanted to compare if the line were equal or not, in my case they are never alike. only the first field match

Comment: [you need a way to read two files parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005887/2152082).

Comment: could be usefull but i still have some trouble with the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each line in 1.csv, look for the name in 2.csv and print combined line.
The REGEX may look a bit strange to you, it's:

`/rc:`: `r`=use Regex, `c:`=use string (necessary, as there could be spaces)
`^`: "Start of string"
`\"`: a literal `"`
`%%~a`: the name without quotes
`/"`: another literal `"`
`,`: a literal `,` (optional)

`"tokens=1,* delims=,"` means "put the first token into `%%m` and all the rest into `%%n`"

Note: there is no `IF`. It's replaced by `findstr`, which extracts just the line, you need.

Note: this may be slow with big files (`2.csv` is read multiple times (as much as there are lines in `1.txt`))

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (1.csv) do (
 for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%m in ('findstr /rc:"^\"%%~a\"," 2.csv') do (
  echo %%a,%%b,%%n
 )
)
```

Names, that aren't in both files, will be skipped.